# Keepkey lists no transaction

Tags: transactions

I sent a test amount of bitcoin to my Keepkey. Coinbase has recorded it and it has been confirmed over 250 times. Yet when I go to my Keepkey it lists NO transactions. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Don't know if you've resolved this or not. How did you go about checking the balance on your KeepKey? Are you doing it via Chrome extension or through app.shapeshift.com or some other method? How did you verify the address came from your KeepKey device?